# Not able to Generate War file through Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, angular5

I am trying to create a war file through Grunt .

What i have did ?

1. I had created basic Angular App .
2. Added Gruntfile.js
3. I have tried with concat and other few task runners  , which is working fine .
4. But when i tried to Create a war file i am not able to generate it .

my war file code snippet in Gruntfile is as follows

```
var taskConfig={
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    war :{
        target:{
            options:{
                war_dist_folder: 'D:/',        
                war_name: 'grunt'            
            },
            files:[{
                expand: true,
                    cwd: 'dist',
                    src: ['**'],
                    dest: ''

            }]
        }
    }
}
grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-war' );
```

[Grunt Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRe8e.png)

[Grunt Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdwIE.png)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you call `initConfig` twice:

```
grunt.initConfig( taskConfig );
grunt.initConfig({ 
  ...
});
```

Tasks from the `taskConfig` are ignored in this case. Just tasks from the second call are available (it is the `concat` task in your case). Use just one config to fix it.

If you want to use multiple configurations, you have to use `grunt.config.merge` method instead of multiple calls of `initConfig`.